# Is it allowed to show information from Wikipedia and other sites on my site?

Tags: wikipedia, copyright

**For Example:** I want to create an institute directory of my country. I want to show institute name, logo, emails, phone numbers and some other information. Now I have two resources, institute website and Wikipedia. Can I copy these information from these two resources without permission.

Remember I don't want to copy any word by word content from these resources. I just want to show their information with their name which is already available on their sites.

Is it allowed without permission ? If yes then please provide some examples.

Comment: Matters and issues of copyright doesn't really scope into this site

Comment: This _may_ be on-topic at [law.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under US laws, a simple list of names isn't copyright-protected but the arrangement (i.e. typographic styling, additional information besides the name, etc) is protected.

If you're unsure what can be borrowed and how to cite information from Wikipedia, you can [consult its distribution license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aText_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License).